# Convert html to word using c#

Tags: c#

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to convert html to word.I am creating html file on local machine then converting it to word file.But word file is not showing correct formatting. It is just showing images. I have referred stackoverflow questions.But I found no luck.
My sample html file is as shown below:-

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>

<head>
  <title="Device Information" />
  <style>
    table.main {
      width: 700px;
      height: 450px;
      background: radial-gradient(#1367AB 0%, #154075 60%);
    }
    td.firsttablerow1 {
      width: 190px;
    }
    td.firsttablerow2 {
      width: auto;
      color: white;
    }
    tr.image1 {
      margin: "15px,20px,30px,40px";
      align-items: stretch;
      height: 100px;
    }
    tr.image2 {
      margin: "0px,20px,30px,40px";
      align-items: stretch;
    }
    tr.text1 {
      color: #DDE9F2;
      align-items: flex-end;
      font-size: 9;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table align="center" class="main">
    <tr>
      <td class="firsttablerow1">
        <table>
          <tr class="image1">
            <td>
              <img src='C:\Jellyfish.jpg' width='200' height='90'>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="image2">
            <td>
              <img src='C:\Desert.jpg' width='150' height='90'>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="text1">
            <td>"abc"</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td class="firsttablerow2">"xyz"</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

My C# code to convert html to word is as shown below.

```
MSWord.Application word = new MSWord.Application { Visible = false };
        word.Documents.Open("htmlfilename", Format: WdOpenFormat.wdOpenFormatWebPages);
        MSWord.Document doc = word.Documents[@"htmlfilename"];
        doc.SaveAs2(@"wordFileName", WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument);
        doc.Close();
        doc = null;
        word.Quit();
        word = null;
```

Edit:-After investigating further ,I found that word is getting created .But It is unable to change background by using radial-gradient .Is there any other way to add radial background?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Hope this solution helps in converting and creating word Docs.

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Xceed.Words.NET;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace MVC_WordDocument.Controllers
{
    public class GenerateDocumentController : Controller
    {
        // GET: GenerateDocument
        public ActionResult GenerateDocument()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public void GenerateDocument(string generate)
        {
            DocX doc = null;

            doc = DocX.Create(Server.MapPath("~/ StudentInformation.docx"), DocumentTypes.Document);

            string Text = @"Student Information";
            doc.InsertParagraph(Text, false).Alignment = Alignment.both;
            doc.InsertParagraph(" ");

            Table table = doc.AddTable(8, 7);
            table.Alignment = Alignment.center;
            table.Design = TableDesign.LightGridAccent2;

            table.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("Student Number");
            table.Rows[0].Cells[1].Paragraphs.First().Append("Name");
            table.Rows[0].Cells[2].Paragraphs.First().Append("Surname");
            table.Rows[0].Cells[3].Paragraphs.First().Append("Email");
            table.Rows[0].Cells[4].Paragraphs.First().Append("Telephone No:");
            table.Rows[0].Cells[5].Paragraphs.First().Append("Mobile Number");
            table.Rows[0].Cells[6].Paragraphs.First().Append("Active");

            doc.InsertTable(table);
            doc.Save();


            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            doc.SaveAs(ms);
            byte[] byteArray = ms.ToArray();
            ms.Flush();
            ms.Close();
            ms.Dispose();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=StudentINFO.docx");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", byteArray.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
            Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use OpenXml.

on .NET 5.0

```
Install-Package HtmlToOpenXml.dll -Version 2.1.0
Install-Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml -Version 2.11.3
```

**ExportService**

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using HtmlToOpenXml;

public MemoryStream ExportToWord()
{
    string htmlValue = "myHtmlCodes";
    
    using MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    using WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(stream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

    MainDocumentPart mainPart = package.MainDocumentPart;
    if (mainPart == null)
    {
        mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();
        new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);
    }

    HtmlConverter converter = new HtmlConverter(mainPart);
    converter.ParseHtml(htmlValue);

    mainPart.Document.Save();

    return stream;
}
```

**ExportController**

```
return File(
        fileContents: stream.ToArray(),
        contentType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        fileDownloadName: $"{fileName}.docx");
```

Comment: This does not convert inline styling to openXml format. I use CKEditor to generate Html and that Html contains lists (ul), headers (h), paragraphs (p) as tags and italic, bold, subscript, justify as text styling. Among all of the items written, it only converts 'p' tag to OpenXml paragraph.

Comment: I just tested this and it converts `<h1>` to heading nad numbered list correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Can try this

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
            Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            wordDoc = word.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            word.Visible = false;
            Object filepath = "c:\\page.html";
            Object confirmconversion = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Object readOnly = false;
            Object saveto = "c:\\doc.pdf";
            Object oallowsubstitution = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            wordDoc = word.Documents.Open(ref filepath, ref confirmconversion, ref readOnly, ref oMissing,
                                          ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                          ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                          ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;
            wordDoc.SaveAs(ref saveto, ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                           ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                           ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oallowsubstitution, ref oMissing,
                           ref oMissing);
```

Comment: I tried this code but I am getting same output.only images are displayed.